# Task.Continue with task.IsFaulted not capturing exceptions

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, async-await, task-parallel-library

I have a sample console application , which is running through infinite loop and send an get request to Web APIU.

When the end point is invalid , I am trying to capture the exception and so does for all other exceptions.

To capture fault , I am writing an continuous task , but it's not getting called.

Here is my code.

```
 HttpClient client = new HttpClient();


            var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
             {
                 var perfService = new PerfCounterService();
                 while (true)
                 {

                     string webAPIPath = $"http://WebAPI/Endpoint";

                     HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(webAPIPath);


                     await Task.Delay(2000);
                 }

             }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);

            task.ContinueWith(t =>
            {
                if (t.IsFaulted)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Faulted....");
                }
            });

            Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: `task.ContinueWith` -> `task.Unwrap().ContinueWith`. Also `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning` have no much meaning here.

Comment: @PetSerAl, perfect , Works fine. If you could add that as answer should work . But why  use unwrap, is this because we have nested await?

Comment: Why so much code for an easy task?

Comment: @SirRufo, need to  send some values to webAPI for long duration ,and thought sync would be a good way to do. Anything wrong here?

Comment: @Simsons `StartNew` do not support `async` methods, so `Task<Task> task` will represent only first synchronous part of `async` lambda, where `task.Result` will contain `Task` representing `async` lambda as whole. P.S. I think, it is better to find right duplicate for this, rather than putting separate answer here.

Comment: @PetSerAl Duplicate located :-)

Comment: @Simsons Look at that [snippet](https://gist.github.com/SirRufo/7f16b6a8841a694fab8c4c267053c260)